# multiple tables sharding with mysql

Tags: mysql, sharding

I'm making a GPS app that will deals with 200 millions records in a table. My initial thought is to divide the table into multiple tables like position_1, position_2, ... and split the data.

My question is: does it have any performance gain with MySQL(innodb) ?

Comment: 1 table, 500+ million rows, query runtime 0.02 secs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is to create the relevant indexes that match the queries.
The [InnoDB table size itself](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/full-table.html) (see the InnoDB specific chapter) shouldn't be a problem.

As long as the indexes are accurate, the application development and maintenance using a single table will be *much easier*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create multiple tables, but you **might** get a performance enhancement by partitioning the single table across different disks. MySQL does actually have support for practitioning.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html

I'd suggest you try to measure performance with and without paritioning before you decide to use it.