# Improve speed of query to mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that sums record from a column for a particular month based on username with latest record for particular user. But the query takes sometimes forever to execute. Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong.

```
Select 
  SUM(t1.some_value) 
from
  tblDemo t1
where 
  t1.month='082017' and 
  t1.username='xyz' and 
  t1.table_no IN ('4a', '4b', '4c', '5a', '5b') and 
  t1.row_version = (
    Select max(t2.row_version) 
    from  tblDemo t2 
    where t2.inv_no = t1.inv_no
  )
```

The table has approx 5 000 records for each month. What can I do to improve speed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql improve SELECT speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775527/mysql-improve-select-speed)

Comment: Number one culprit is often ineffective or missing indexes. That's what `EXPLAIN` can help diagnose.

Comment: Thanks a lot tadman it resolved the issue and the difference is excellent.

Comment: In my experience, an uncorrelated subquery will sometimes outperform a correlated one. Also, consider storing dates as dates. It can make a considerable difference when searching across a range.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry will try that.