# START TRANSACTION inside BEGIN ... END context or outside and LOOP syntax

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, transactions

I have two questions about Compound-Statement and Transactions in MySQL.

FIRST:

There are two notes in MySQL Manual:

> Note
>
> Within all stored programs, the parser treats BEGIN [WORK] as the
>   beginning of a BEGIN ... END block. To begin a transaction in this
>   context, use START TRANSACTION instead.
>
> Note
>
> Within all stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers,
>   and events), the parser treats BEGIN [WORK] as the beginning of a
>   BEGIN ... END block. Begin a transaction in this context with START
>   TRANSACTION instead.

I can't understand what exactly is meant. They mean that I have to put `START TRANSACTION` instead of `BEGIN` or right after `BEGIN`?

```
// 1st variant:

BEGIN
   START TRANSACTION
   COMMIT
END


// 2nd variant:

START TRANSACTION
COMMIT
END
```

Which one is the right way, 1st variant or 2nd variant?

SECOND:

I don't want to create a Stored Procedure or Function. I just want to create a Compound-Statement Block with a loop inside it in the general flow, like this:

```
USE 'someDb';
START TRANSACTION
   ... create table statement
   ... insert statement

// now I want to implement some insert/select statements using loop, I do as follows:

DELIMITER $
BEGIN
  SET @n = 1, @m = 2;
  lab1: LOOP

   ... some insert, select statements here

   END LOOP lab1;
END $
DELIMITER ;

END

COMMIT
```

Is it possible such kind of structure? Because I have an error thrown:

```
Query: BEGIN SET @n = 1, @m = 2; lab1: LOOP SELECT ...
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @n = 1, @m = 2;
lab1: LOOP SELECT ...
```

My questions are:

1. Is it allowed to use `BEGIN...END` just in general flow without creating and using Stored Procedures or Functions?
2. Is it allowed to use `BEGIN...END` inside of `START TRANSACTION...COMMIT` or I have to put `START TRANSACTION...COMMIT` inside of `BEGIN...END`?

   ```
   BEGIN
      START TRANSACTION
      COMMIT
   END

   // vs.

   START TRANSACTION
      BEGIN
      END
   COMMIT
   ```
3. Do I by all means have to use `BEGIN...END` if I want to use only `LOOP`? May I just use `LOOP` syntax without starting `BEGIN...END`? The only example in the manual for `LOOP` is this:

   ```
     CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
        BEGIN
          label1: LOOP
            ...
   ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. > Is it allowed to use BEGIN...END just in general flow without creating and using Stored Procedures or Functions?

   No: compound statements can only be used within the body of stored programs.
2. > Is it allowed to use `BEGIN...END` inside of `START TRANSACTION...COMMIT` or I have to put `START TRANSACTION...COMMIT` inside of `BEGIN...END`?

   `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` are separate statements.  If you want the body of a stored program to contain multiple statements, it will need to enclose those statements in some sort of compound statement block such as `BEGIN ... END` (which is similar to enclosing a block of statements in braces `{ ... }` within a C-like language).

   That said, you *could* have a stored program which contains only the single-statement `START TRANSACTION;` or `COMMIT;`—such a program would not require any compound statement block and would merely commence a new / commit the current transaction respectively.

   Outside of a stored program, where compound statement blocks are not permitted, you can issue `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` statements as & when required.
3. > Do I by all means have to use `BEGIN...END` if I want to use only `LOOP`? May I just use `LOOP` syntax without starting `BEGIN...END`?

   `LOOP` is also a compound statement block, which is only valid within a stored procedure.  It is not *necessary* to enclose a `LOOP` block within a `BEGIN ... END` block, although it is usual (as otherwise it is difficult to perform any required loop initialisation).

In your case, where you apparently want to insert data into a table from a looping construct, you will either need to:

- define a stored program in which you use `LOOP`;
- iterate a loop in an external program that executes database queries on each iteration; or
- redefine your logic in terms of sets upon which SQL can directly operate.

Comment: Why can loops only exist within a stored proc? Seems retarded to have to create a temporary stored proc just to do a simple loop insert.....

Comment: @Pacerier: because that's business logic that belongs in your application code, not the database layer.

Comment: @eggyal while I fully agree with you Pacerier has a very valid point, why is mysql behaving different for stored programs vs standard queries

Comment: @BobTheJanitor: SQL is declarative, and therefore does not have procedural language constructs such as loops. Stored procedures look like SQL, but the name kinda gives it away: they are procedural, not declarative (and therefore do support looping constructs).  That said, most behaviour one might like to accomplish with a procedural loop can (and should) be rewritten into a declarative form so that it can be expressed in pure SQL without any need for a sproc.