# MySQL Transaction - How to group?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just learned about transaction few days ago and I find it very useful in some situation like when I update few tables and the script may fail in the middle of the operation, quite nice.

However, how can I group them ? It can happen that a query is ran between two queries in the transaction but I don't want it to rollback. Is there a way that I can group query without a new connection ?

I have searched but I got poor to nothing result.

I am using InnoDB, PHP/PDO + MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but i just don't catch what you mean by "grouping" transactions. Can you explain in more detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with the `begin-end`, where you can execute multiple queries inside those tags.  You are working with TRANSACTIONS, so you only have two options COMMIT and ROLLBACK, if your query is not successful it will ROLLBACK (no more option), Please take a look to this post

[START TRANSACTION inside BEGIN ... END context or outside and LOOP syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259675/start-transaction-inside-begin-end-context-or-outside-and-loop-syntax)