# MySQL procedure to insert multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, procedure

I'm trying to write a procedure in MySQL to execute 30 (or more) inserts into a table. The table has other fields such `ID` etc, but `ID` is an `auto_increment` field and the others are not important.

This is where I got so far looking at [other StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;

WHILE i < 30
    INSERT INTO account (login, password)
    SELECT concat('test', i), '*00A51F3F48415C7D4E8908980D443C29C69B60C9';

    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
COMMIT; 
END #

DELIMITER;

CALL test();
```

But MySQL returns the error 1064 "*Syntax error on line 7, check your manual*". Line 7 is the one that begins with `WHILE`.

I also tried with this `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO account (login, password)
VALUES (concat('test', i), '*00A51F3F48415C7D4E8908980D443C29C69B60C9');
```

But without any luck, MySQL gives back the same error.

Is there something I'm missing? Or this is something that just can't be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword [DO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/while.html) is missing:

```
WHILE Syntax
[begin_label:] WHILE search_condition DO
    statement_list
END WHILE [end_label]
```

So your SQL should be:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;

-- next line needs a DO at the end
WHILE i < 30 DO                    
    INSERT INTO account (login, password)
    SELECT concat('test', i), '*00A51F3F48415C7D4E8908980D443C29C69B60C9';

    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
COMMIT; 
END #

DELIMITER;
```