# Is somehow possible to create select a series in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, range

Is possible to select a numerical series or date series in SQL? Like create a table with N rows like 1 to 10:

```
1
2
3
... 
10
```

or

```
2010-01-01  
2010-02-01
...  
2010-12-01
```

Comment: yes, it is possible, for example with temp table and for loop, like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql

Comment: not create a new table, but just select as a helper for another queries

Comment: It's possible, but not usually necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install [common_schema](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html), you can use the `numbers` table to easily create queries to output those types of ranges.

For example, these 2 queries will produce the output from your examples:

```
select n 
from common_schema.numbers 
where n between 1 and 10
order by n

select ('2010-01-01' + interval n month) 
from common_schema.numbers 
where n between 0 and 11
order by n
```

Answer (score 1):

An SQL solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as id
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep!  Both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server (and others) have a BETWEEN operator.  I don't remember off the top of my head if it's inclusive or exclusive, but here's a starting point!

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: "between" operator is like a ">"  and "<" operator, it does not generate a table with a range.