# Select differents database for join - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to do a sql script to retrieve info from a main table and join them with data from a table in another database (Same server). The hard part is that for each row in the "main" table, the data that I have to join is in a different database.

I am not sure how I would proceed to do that, I think the only way would be to do some kind of loop. Am I right?

Here is how my two tables look like:

```
Main table:  
    main_id  
    database_name

other tables:  
    other_id  
    other_name
```

I'd like the result to be something like:

```
main_id  
database_name  
other_name
```

Edit: I am trying to write a stored procedure

Comment: How many "different" databases do you have and is this info available at design time?

Comment: Each row represent a database. It is a list clients and I need to go fetch the name of the client in its database. The number is unknown at design time as I could get more clients

Comment: @RyanVincent The question is not the same. The name of the database is inside a column of the main table.

Comment: Unless your table references just few "other" databases and all their names are known upfront, you are looking at creating a stored procedure.

Comment: @PM77-1 I should have said that I already am inside a stored proc. How would I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that in mysql, you can (or rather: have to) use dynamic sql to generate an sql statement that has variable code (like database names) in it.

Try

```
set @stmt = 
  (select group_concat(concat(
                 'select * from main_table m ',
                 'join ',database_name,'.other_table o ', 
                 'on m.database_name = ''',database_name,''' ',
                 'and m.main_id = o.other_id ') 
                 SEPARATOR ' union all ')
   from (select database_name 
         from main_table 
         group by database_name) as dbdata);

prepare stmt from @stmt;
execute stmt;
```

This will first get all distinct `database_name`, then generate code that will join your entries from your `main_table` with the correct database.

It will not check if all databases exists, and the whole statement will fail if one doesn't, but you can of course check the databases first in `information_schema` beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the "Union" option.

Or you could use temprary tables; insert from a select and later show the result.

Regards

Comment: I got it. The problem is "the tables" are in another database right??
You can use 
Select * from databaseName.table.

Comment: Please re-read the question. The problem is that database names are dependent on the content of a primary database.

Comment: As @PM77-1 said, each row contains a database name as a varchar and I need to go fetch a name in that database with it. I don't think it is possible to do something like `INNER JOIN database_name.other_table` where `database_name` is the name of a column.

Comment: Ok. You could use a structured procedure. Where you use "if then else" situation. Or you can use the solution:
"prepare stmt from @stmt;
execute stmt;"

Comment: Ohh!! Right.

You can use a "cursor". And for each row use an especific condition.
For instance:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql