# SQL loop with current and previous values

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, cursor

I need to loop through rows which has id and when looping i need to check current and previous values.

I have a cursor to fetch them :

```
DECLARE idCur CURSOR FOR SELECT MessageId FROM EMMessages;
```

So now i need to loop through these values and compare them when looping:
For example i have ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
I want to compare 1 and 2 then 2 and 3 and so on..
How in sql i should declare this n and n-1 variable or should i decalare n and n+1.

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: What if you have [1, 2, 4]?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this previous answer

[For loop example in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql)

Else, You can use another code together with sql to achieve this. Such as using for loop in php.