# In MySQL DB, how do I create a loop to insert such data?

Tags: mysql

I need to insert thousands of rows in a table in MYSQL DB, by the given index value, such as:

```
"
insert into Table_1 ( column_A, column_B ) values ( 'A0001', 'B0001');
insert into Table_1 ( column_A, column_B ) values ( 'A0002', 'B0002');
insert into Table_1 ( column_A, column_B ) values ( 'A0003', 'B0003');
insert into Table_1 ( column_A, column_B ) values ( 'A0004', 'B0004');
....
insert into Table_1 ( column_A, column_B ) values ( 'A9999', 'B9999');
".
```

How do I do such in a loop way in MySQL DB ?

Thanks a lot !

Jack

Comment: how you obtain the values  for insert  .. (external files?? query from another table?)

Comment: This is an example of how to use a loop in MySQL [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql#5126655](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125096/for-loop-example-in-mysql#5126655)

Comment: Thost values are originated from the index value, starring from 1, 2, 3, ... till 9999.  and I need to insert that many rows in that table.  I am looking for a loop way to do that.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using the mysql workbench 8.0

Comment: @user3595231: The client (version) doesn't matter, what's the server version? You can use `select version();` to find out.

Comment: 10.1.19-MariaDB

Comment: Any chance you can update to at least 10.2.2? That would support recursive CTEs, which could make this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not work that way (mostly).   One SQL statement executes against a set of data.  However, you can certainly bulk insert, like so:

insert into Table_1 ( column_A, column_B ) 
values ( 'A0001', 'B0001'),
       ( 'A0002', 'B0002'),
       ( 'A0003', 'B0003'),
       ( 'A0004', 'B0004');

if you are including **all** columns in the table, in order, you can omit the column names portion like so:

insert into Table_1 
values ( 'A0001', 'B0001'),
       ( 'A0002', 'B0002'),
       ( 'A0003', 'B0003'),
       ( 'A0004', 'B0004');

If you **really** need to loop, you can create a stored procedure to do so.  Stored procedures have a lot of uses, but generally there is another reason to use a stored procedure than just looping.

Comment: Sorry I was looking at  "loop" "store procedure" way, but I am not sure is how to generate the concatenated column values, such as  1 becomes  "A0001", while 9999 becomes  "A9999" ?