# Create user after insert in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to create a new user with the same initial password every time I insert a row with the username in the table.

I tried but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Professeur (
professeur_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
prenom varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
name varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
titre char DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (professeur_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;


CREATE trigger trig_prof AFTER INSERT ON Professeur
FOR EACH ROW CREATE OR replace USER NEW.name@localhost identified BY pwd0;
```

**ERROR:**

```
    ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'USER NEW.name@localhost identified BY pwd0' at line 2
```

Comment: (1) There is no password column in your table.  (2) "Professeur" is an odd name for a user table.  (3) I sure hope you are not storing free text passwords.

Comment: You should post an error with your " it doesn't work:" statement witch does not mean anything to us. I added it for you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. (1) I don't want to store password in my table. (2) "Professeur" means teacher in French (3) No I'm not. I want to initialize each user account with the same password. After that they can choose their own password.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers have several limitations as described in the [fine manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-limitations/):

***"Triggers cannot operate on any tables in the mysql, information_schema or performance_schema database."***

Since users are stored in mysql schema (either in global_priv or user) this can't work.

Comment: OK thank you. So I have to find an other way: cursor and Loop ?

Comment: You should execute the CREATE USER from your application code, after the INSERT is done.

Comment: @BillKarwin It's planned.

But, for demonstration purposes, with a sql script, I initialize the Teacher table with a list of fictitious teachers to whom I want to give the rights to connect with an sql role of Teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Do things a different way...

Write a Stored Procedure that both creates the table and adds the user.  See `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` for how to temporarily give an enduser root permission.  But be aware of the security implications.

Then, to add the table and the user, it is one `CALL` statement.

Comment: The sql script will be executed as root so no problem with that.

I figured out how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839013/5952631

Anything else to know?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with a procedure as Rick James has suggested and with Prepared Statements https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

I put the following code in my script and I execute the source command `SOURCE initdb_gestiondesnotes.SQL`

After that I call the procedure with: `CALL create_professeur();`

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE CREATE_PROFESSEUR()

   BEGIN
      DECLARE v_a INT Default 1 ;
      DECLARE v_nom VARCHAR(42);
      DECLARE v_prenom VARCHAR(42);
      DECLARE v_login VARCHAR(84);
      DECLARE v_titre VARCHAR(5);
      DECLARE v_pwd VARCHAR(5);
      SET v_pwd = 'p';
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET v_nom = CONCAT("prof", LPAD(CAST(v_a AS CHAR), 3, '0'));
         SET v_prenom = CONCAT("prenom", LPAD(CAST(v_a AS CHAR), 3, '0'));
         SET v_titre = CASE WHEN RAND() > .5
                  THEN 'M'
                  ELSE 'F' END;
         INSERT INTO Professeur (prenom, nom, titre) VALUES (v_prenom, v_nom, v_titre);
         SET v_login = CONCAT(v_prenom, v_nom);
         SET @sql1 = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE USER ', v_login, '@localhost identified BY  \'p\' ');
         PREPARE stm1 FROM @sql1;
         EXECUTE stm1;
         SET @sql2 = CONCAT('GRANT role_professeur TO ', v_login, '@localhost');
         PREPARE stm2 FROM @sql2;
         EXECUTE stm2;
         SET @sql3 = CONCAT('SET DEFAULT ROLE role_professeur FOR ', v_login, '@localhost');
         PREPARE stm3 FROM @sql3;
         EXECUTE stm3;
         SET v_a=v_a+1;
         IF v_a=51 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm1;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm2;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm3;      
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now I hove 50 user with `prenom001prof001`, `prenom002prof002`... as login and 'p' as password. Again with prepared statements I gave each user the role of `role_professeur`.