# how to pass multiple variables in WHERE ... IN in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new in mysql. I have declared a variable in a store procedure like this:

```
DECLARE ids VARCHAR(255);
SET ids = '51,254,22';
```

How can I pass this to where ... in clause like this?

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE id IN (ids);
```

by writing the above code only **first row** is in the output.
How can I get the correct answer including all rows that have been found?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20769230/6950079

Comment: DECLARE ids VARCHAR(255);
SET ids = '''51'',''254'',''22''';