# Yii2 Session Storage in Database, too many rows?

Tags: php, session, yii2

I am using Yii2 DbSession but after few days I am noticing that the session  table now has even those rows whose expiry was few days ago. Currently it has 23376 rows and it is continuously increasing.

Gc Probability is 0 and Session Timeout is 1440

Is there something wrong?

--EDIT--
Actually I want to know that is the gcprobability value to 0 is causing not cleaning of expired session rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 Session Storage in DB, too many rows? Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309946/yii2-session-storage-in-db-too-many-rows-performance)

Comment: As @SilverFire said, all is okay, but im wondering why you set GcPropability to 0?

Comment: I didn't set gcProbability to 0. It is the default setting server has. What should be its correct value?

Comment: Well, i thought you set `$gCProbability` property of `yii\web\DbSession`, otherwise it should be okay.

Comment: For tests, you can change `gcPropability` do 50 (for 50%), create some new sessions (old sessions deleting is fired when new one comes) and check if it helps. Standard Yii2 value of `gcPropability` is 1.

Comment: I set it to 1 and now my session table rows went to 340 from 23376.
Thank you!