# Optimize mysql NOT IN query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

I have two tables users, and postmeta. I want to take users id's from users table and want to filter users id's which are not present in postmeta table.

Here is my mysql query

```
SELECT u.ID from users WHERE u.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) from postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_customer_user')
```

Above query is working fine but as i have thousands of users and also postmeta table is large it is taking too much time.

Can anyone help me on how to optimize this query?

[image]
[image: Post Meta Table]

Comment: you should read this post first, all you need is at theese post
[large table optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557838/mysql-optimization-of-huge-table)

Comment: Try this: `SELECT DISTINCT(u.id) 
from users AS u, postmeta AS p
WHERE p.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND 
u.id <> p.meta_value
`

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Are the tables `ENGINE=InnoDB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.ID
    FROM  users
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM postmeta
                WHERE meta_key = '_customer_user'
                  AND meta_value = u.ID )
```

Since this smells like WP, I recommend some tips on wp_postmeta performance here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta  (I don't think the tips will significantly help *this* query.)

Comment: Unfortunately query is still taking a lot of time as i have around 2 lakh (2 hundred thousands) users in my user table.

Comment: How many rows in `postmeta` have `meta_key = '_customer_user'`?

Comment: Assuming `meta_value` is `LONGTEXT`, there is no good way to avoid scanning all 4M rows for `_customer_user`.  To put it bluntly, the link between users and customers _must_ be done with a column, _not_ a "postmeta" key-value mechanism.  If you can't achieve that in WP, then I recommend you abandon WP.

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can run mysql count function on the following query to get the total number of rows returned.
<code>
SELECT u.ID FROM wp_users AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_comments AS c ON u.ID = c.user_id LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts AS p ON u.ID = p.post_author LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_links AS l ON u.ID = l.link_owner WHERE c.user_id IS NULL AND p.post_author IS NULL AND l.link_owner IS NULL AND YEAR(u.user_registered) = 2017 AND u.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_key` = '_customer_user' ) GROUP BY u.ID</code>

Comment: @mubashir - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS x;`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the expalin,and use not exists replaced

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT u.ID
FROM diet_users AS u
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT pm.meta_value
     FROM diet_postmeta AS pm
     WHERE meta_key = '_customer_user'
       AND pm.meta_value = u.ID)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Remove `DISTINCT`, it is totally useless.