# One big table or many small tables

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, database-design

I am developing a website (WordPress MU - based). In this website, users can create their own blogs, can fully customize their own blogs (change background, write articles...), add more users to their blogs...

The most common query is to get articles of a blog. 2 different blogs are almost not related.

The information of the blogs can be stored in database in 2 ways:

1. A few tables containing all the information, each blog is identified
   by blog_id.
2. Many groups of tables. Each group of tables contains all information of a blog. More blogs, create more tables.

My questions are:

1. In term of performance, which one is better?
2. WordPress actually uses the second design. If the number of blogs
       is    very large (thousands) then the number of tables can be
   tens
       of    thousands. Does this cause any problem? Is there a limit
   of
       number of    tables of a MySQL database?

Comment: this might enlighten you somewhat - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601

Comment: Thank you f00, it's really helpful. I didn't find this before asking this question. By the way, do you have any idea about my second question?

Answer (score 4):

Go for option #1 - it's called [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: wp_blogs only stores blog ID, blog url... Most information of a blog is stored in tables created for that blog (e.g wp_1_posts, wp_1_users, wp_1_options...)

Comment: My mistake. But you should definitely go for option #1!

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of code maintainability, I beg you to go for option 1.

Comment: You bet. "Urge", maybe? How about "pray"? :)

Comment: I was thinking "For the love of all that is Holy and to take pity on those that follow, go with option 1." might work as well... ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. They should both really perform very similarly, given appropriate indexing
2. Managing a large number of tables is more problematic, especially with schema changes

Comment: 1. I don't really understand what you meant by "given appropriate indexing"? Is the database indexed the same way (by MySQL) for both designs? I thought that WordPress uses the second design because the blogs are almost not connected, separating them into many tables might make it faster.
2. Yes you are right. I use phpMyAdmin and it doesn't work properly when the number of tables is more than 10000.

Comment: @Jack When a table is properly designed and indexed, the size of the table has very little to do with the speed of retrieving (the same number of) records.  That's the purpose of indexing - reducing the search time to an O(log n) operation, this grows slowly compared to n.  Assuming that the table has a key which allows the index to be "partitioned" by blog first, the retrieval should be largely equivalent.  It's usually a binary search.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Questions

Answer (score 0):

I did some searches and I think I saw more often people saying they would prefer one table with many data than many tables. They say it's easier to maintain.

Here is some texts of database normalization :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878 
http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/

Good luck!