# How to create product table in which each product is under multiple categories in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, optimization

I have 2 MySQL tables:

```
categories (id int, name varchar(1000))
```

And

```
products (id int, name varchar(1000))
```

Each product can be under multiple categories. I'm thinking of adding column "category_ids" into the table 'products' with category Ids separated by semicolons, but this method is inconvenient for MySQL query.

Any other possible methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make third table which have refernce to both table as in below image

[image]

Comment: oh great, how could i forget this method of mapping between 2 tables, tks for reminding me

Answer (score 5):

Create a table that matches products with categories:

```
product_id category_id
1          1
1          2
2          5
3          5
3          2
```

etc. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a junction table linking the two:

```
**product_categories**
productid (FK ref product.id)
categoryid (FK ref categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a many to many relationship....

In order to map many to many relationship, u will need another table

```
categories_products(id, category_id, product_id)
```

so one product can come under many categories and similarly one category can hold many products.

Product table will have one to many relationship with categories_products table 
Categories table will also have one to many relationip with categories_products table

thats a standard way to implement many to many relationships

Comment: a clustered composite primary key (category_id, product_id) would better enforce integrity and be much more performant - ditch the pointless surrogate PK and read up on index types http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601