# Best storage engine for database with 10,000,000 rows

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

I have a database table with 10,000,000+ rows which I process to create a new table. What is the best type of storage engine for reading?

Currently I use:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `packages_unsorted` SET `acv_return_viadetails` = '0';";
```

Then to select the records:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `packages_unsorted` WHERE `acv_return_viadetails` = '0' LIMIT 1000;";
```

I collect the primary key `id` into an array called $ids and I process the records and write the data to a CSV file for import at the end of each 1000 rows.
I then update the acv_return_viadetails field with:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `packages_unsorted` SET `acv_return_viadetails` = '1' WHERE `id` IN ('".implode("','",$ids)."') LIMIT 1000;";
```

As the above is the only write to the table and I select all fields every time. Should I be using a memory table or some other type of storage engine to make things faster? Or are there any other optimizations I could introduce that would speed things up?

Also what would be a reasonable my.cnf configuration for such an operation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're looking for advanced techniques in tuning your MySQL setup I would highly recommend http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/ to determine all the tweaks you can do.  Can't see why you can't just use `InnoDb` and make sure `acv_return_viadetails` has an `INDEX`.  Maybe if we knew a little bit more about your dataset it might make sense to break it up into smaller tables or to reorganize the data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try Innodb but I can't really split the data up because it's a direct CSV import using LOAD DATA INFILE - approx 90 fields * 10M rows.

Comment: innodb - clustered primary keys see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601

Comment: @Andy ofc you can split the data up. You load the file into a staging table then run some sprocs which populate your normalised tables.

Comment: @f00 Thanks, that's essentially what I'm doing now. I import the CSV as is into the staging table packages_unsorted. I then load chunks of data (1000 records at a time to let the mysql server free for other queries). I build a CSV file for import at the end of the procedure. It's taking around 6 hours to complete and I'm wondering if another storage engine would be more appropriate. There is only one index, other than the primary key and I use that for flagging the records I've normalised so I don't think clustered indexes will help me either. I guess I'll have to accept the time it takes. :)

Comment: Why are you creating a CSV file at the end of the procedure? I think it will be faster if you just added your normalized records to a table instead of creating the CSV and then importing it. Also, I think you can avoid loading the original CSV to the database - just parse it in PHP itself and insert the processed data into a table. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1) Replace

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `packages_unsorted` WHERE `acv_return_viadetails` = '0' LIMIT 1000;";
```

with

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `packages_unsorted` WHERE `acv_return_viadetails` = '0' LIMIT 1000;";
```

2) Check if it is possible to load all the `ids` at once without the 1000 limit. With 10M records, it should take only a few hundred MBs to load all the `ids`.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `packages_unsorted`";
```

If not, consider increasing the limit.

3) You can try something like the following instead of using `acv_return_viadetails`:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `packages_unsorted` LIMIT 0, 1000;";
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `packages_unsorted` LIMIT 1000, 1000;";
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `packages_unsorted` LIMIT 2000, 1000;";
```

Comment: Thanks I understand but I need all of the fields from the table to process so I have to select * each time. I also need to chunk (by 1000) it so it releases the mysql server for queries on other tables so I can't grab all ids either :(

Comment: Maybe you could just select the `id`, store them in a PHP list and then process them one-by-one. I believe grabbing all ids should not take too many resources.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on the acv_return_viadetails field?

If you're looking at speeding up the import, I just made a program in C++ to import a 300MB file into mysql in 65s. Perhaps you can adapt it for you use.

See https://github.com/homer6/import-geoip-data

Comment: +1 for sharing. Can you tell me what is < and > in c++ means:    std::auto_ptr< sql::Connection > temp_connection?

Comment: That's a template. It allows you to create many different types of classes. For example vector<int> creates a vector (which is a collection) of ints. Whereas vector<string> creates a vector of strings. In the case you mentioned, it creates an auto_ptr to an sql::Connection

Comment: Yes I have an index on `acv_return_viadetails` but I only have access to PHP on the server so I can't use the C++ app. I will use it for other things though :)