# mysql index for speed

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a table which will be about 2 - 5 million rows on average.  It has a primary key/index called 'instruction_id' and another indexed field called 'mode'.  now 'instruction_id' is of course unique since it is the primary key but 'mode' will only be one of 3 different values.  The query I run all the time is

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE mode = 'value1' ORDER BY instruction_id LIMIT 50
```

This currently takes about 25 sec ( > 1 sec is unacceptably long) but there are only 600K rows right now so it will get worse as the table grows.  Would indexing in a different way help?  If I index instruction_id and mode together will that make a difference?  If I somehow am able to naturally order the table by instruction_id so I don't have to ask for the order by would be another way around this but I don't know how to do that...  Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you sure the query is taking that long to execute. It will take time to retrieve 200K rows - especially if the server is remote. Providing the EXPLAIN output of your query would help too

Comment: @AdrianCornish, note the `LIMIT 50`.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo Good point - although the storage engine may be returning 200K rows then because the ORDER BY/LIMIT is being applied outside the storage engine by MySQL itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try index on (mode, instruction_id), in that order.

The reasoning behind that index is that it creates an index like this

```
mode  instruction_id
A     1
A     3
A     4
A     5
A     10
A     11
B     2
B     8
B     12
B     13
B     14
C     6
C     7
C     9
C     15
C     16
C     17
```

If you search for mode B the sql server can search the index with a binary search on mode until it finds the first B, then it can simply output the next `n` rows. This would be really fast, about 22 compares for 4M rows.

Always use `ORDER BY` if you expect the result to be ordered, regardless of how the data is stored. The query engine might choose a query plan that output the rows in a different order than the order of the PK (maybe not in such simple cases as this, but in general).

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the following links relating to innodb clustered indexes

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html
- http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/
- [MySQL and NoSQL: Help me to choose the right one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601)

Then build your schema something along the lines of:

```
drop table if exists instruction_modes;
create table instruction_modes
(
mode_id smallint unsigned not null,
instruction_id int unsigned not null,
primary key (mode_id, instruction_id), -- note the clustered composite PK order !
unique key (instruction_id)
)
engine = innodb;
```

Cold (mysql restarted) runtime performance as follows:

```
select count(*) from instruction_modes;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.54 sec)

select distinct mode_id from instruction_modes;
+---------+
| mode_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       3 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.06 sec)

select * from instruction_modes where mode_id = 2 order by instruction_id limit 10;
+---------+----------------+
| mode_id | instruction_id |
+---------+----------------+
|       2 |              2 |
|       2 |              3 |
|       2 |              4 |
|       2 |              5 |
|       2 |              6 |
|       2 |              9 |
|       2 |             14 |
|       2 |             25 |
|       2 |             28 |
|       2 |             32 |
+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

0.04 seconds cold seems pretty performant.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you.  I had already accpeted Albin Sunnanbo answer but I +1'ed this one because I think that this is what I will do to get the extra performance boost I am looking for.  I actually had already checked out the xaprb link and it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD UNIQUE  (`mode`, instruction_id);
```

Then:

```
SELECT A.* FROM tablename A JOIN (
     SELECT instruction_id FROM tablename 
     WHERE mode = 'value1' 
     ORDER BY instruction_id LIMIT 50
     ) B 
ON (A.instruction_id = B.instruction_id);
```

I have found for large tables that approach seems to work good for speed as the subquery should only be using the index.

I use a similar query on a table with >100mil records and it returns results in 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Is 'mode' a character field? If it's only ever going to hold 3 possible values, it sounds like you should make it an enum field, which will still return you the text string but is stored internally as a number.

You should also follow Albin's advice on indexing, which will benefit you further.

Comment: Thank you and good point.  Unfortunately what I am using it for provides more maintainability and is easier to modify if I don't use enum type values but if I need some extra performance I will look back here.