# Which DB used for the application that deals with milions of the rows

Tags: database, performance, database-design

I am creating an application that is going to handle millions of rows per month. I have a major concern about the database performance that can handle these large numbers of rows as well give fast result.

I have an option for the databases like MySQL, SQL Server, ORACLE, DB2...

Hopefully somebody could give me the good way to over come with these problem.

Comment: All of the choices you listed should have no trouble with millions of records per month if properly configured.  If you edit your question to offer more details about your situation or more specific questions, the answers you get will probably be more helplful.

Comment: you might find the following of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601

Answer (score 1):

RDBMSes don't have any problem with what you mentioned, the problem is you (sorry for that).

- how do you design your database schema?
- how do you chache your queries?
- how do you use RDBMS functions (in efficient or inefficient way)?
- database design
- normalization
- replication
- ...

The list goes on, just try to learn more about one of them (MySQL, SQL, Oracle) in more practical way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i pretty much aware of this points,but if RDBMS is the only thing that care of your Db,Why number of the DB solutions are introduce in the market?

Comment: I couldn't get your point, do mean why do we have different RDBMSes?

Comment: There actually aren't a large number of RDBMs in the market with significant market share. The shakeout for relational database software happened in the 1990s.