# Speed up MYSQL INNER JOIN Query Across Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, join

The purpose of this query is to act like a search. Unfortunately the query is currently running from 1.5 to 2 seconds which is unacceptable. After running EXPLAIN on the query I see it's using *"Using temporary; Using filesort"* and no indexes. However, I'm not exactly sure where you could put an index on this query.

The ORDER BY also slows the query down a whole lot as well but it's needed.
Any suggestions on how to improve this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.date,
(
  SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = pt.post_id
) as t_count 
FROM post_tags pt 
INNER JOIN posts p 
  ON (pt.post_id = p.id) 
WHERE pt.t_id IN (7,456)
ORDER BY t_count, p.s_count DESC, p.id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Here is the EXPAIN statement: https://gist.github.com/e742982e435cf082c033

Comment: Can you post full output of explain as well.

Comment: Is it not more efficient to use count(pt.post_id) and GROUP BY p.id and p.date? You can get rid of the subquery then for starters.

Comment: @AdrianCornish I've added the EXPLAIN statement to the post and here: https://gist.github.com/e742982e435cf082c033.

Comment: @dash Removing " SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = pt.post_id" would remove a sort on the temp "t_count" column which is rather important with this query.

Comment: myisam or innodb ? if using mysiam read the following links about clustered indexes. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/ and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting as:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.date
     , COUNT(*) AS t_count 
FROM posts p
  INNER JOIN post_tags pts 
    ON pts.post_id = p.id
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM post_tags pt
        WHERE pt.post_id = p.id
          AND pt.t_id IN (7,456)
      )
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY t_count, p.s_count DESC, p.id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50 ;
```

Comment: Can you add the EXPLAIN for this one?

Comment: The explain for your query seems to be the same as my original query: https://gist.github.com/c97338f3abf10283955f

Comment: Can you add the tables definitions and the indexes you have?

Comment: Does `post_tags.t_id` have an index?

Comment: After adding an index to post_tags.t_id it seems give a slight advantage, but not much. Ideally this query would be at least under 800ms.

Comment: As a guess add a composite index on pt.t_id, pt.post_id and also on p.s_count,p.id

Comment: @AdrianCornish Both of those indexes have already been set. It looks like the majority of the slowness is caused by the ORDER BY.

Comment: That would make sense - since the ORDER BY has to been run totally to satisfy your LIMIT clause - out of interest - if you feel like replying again :-) - what mysql version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you see "Using temporary;" in your exlain, that usualy mean you have not enought memory for your "order by" or other operation.

For this query  i think you have increase in my.conf

```
sort_buffer_size=128M
```