# Is there a simpler way to achieve this style of user messaging?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, innodb

I have created a messaging system for users, it allows them to send a message to another user. If it is the first time they have spoken then a new conversation is initiated, if not the old conversation continues.

The users inbox lists all conversations the user has had with all other users, these are then ordered by the conversation which has the latest post in it.

A user can only have one conversation with another user.

When a user clicks one of these conversations they are taken to a page showing the whole conversation they've had with newest posts at the top. So it's kind of like a messaging chat functionality.

I have two tables:

- userconversation
- usermessages

**userconversation**

Contains an auto increment id which is the conversation id, along with the userId and the friendId.

Whoever initates the first conversation will always be userId and the recipient friendId, this will then never change for that conversation.

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | userId | friendId |
+----+--------+----------+
```

**usermessages**

Contains the specific messages, along with a read flag, the time and conversationId

```
+----+---------+--------+------+------+----------------+
| id | message | userId | read | time | conversationId |
+----+---------+--------+------+------+----------------+
```

**How it works**

When a user goes to message another user, a query will run to check if both users have a match in the userconversation table, if so that `conversationId` is used and the conversation carries on, if not a new row is created for them with a unique `conversationId`.

**Where it gets complicated**

So far all is well, however when it comes to displaying the message inbox of all conversations, sorted on the latest post, it get's tricky to do with one query..

To be able to list the conversations you must first find the latest post of each conversation, but as you can't order by before a group this is impossible to do with one query on two tables, so I have to use the following:

```
SELECT  
    c.id,
    c.userId,
    c.friendId,
    m2.message,
    m2.read,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m2.time),      
    user1.username,
    user2.username  
FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(m1.id) AS MessageID 
     FROM usermessages m1 
     GROUP BY m1.conversationId) latest_msg

INNER JOIN usermessages m2 ON latest_msg.MessageID = m2.id 
INNER JOIN userconversation c ON m2.conversationId = c.id
INNER JOIN user user1 ON c.userId = user.id
INNER JOIN user user2 ON c.friendId = user.id

WHERE c.userId = :userId OR c.friendId = :userId
ORDER BY m2.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I just don't think this is the best way it can be done but can't think of others ways too approach it?

The database table is InnoDB to speed up the joins and improve data integrity so I can't have two auto increment rows.

Is there another way I could get rid of the userconversation table and create a unique Id to put in the conversationId column? I could then just move the userId and friendId over to usermessages ... but this would create a lot of redundant data?

Comment: Well written question, bravo sir.

Comment: now this is what i call a good explanation. a little bit complex, but well explained. +1

Comment: Don't you track senders of each message here? For a conversation between Alice and Bob, how do you distinguish who sent which message? Or the two directions make two separate conversations?

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes, I missed that column, updated.

Comment: @Silver89: OK, see the update. Nice post, BTW.

Comment: @Silver89 I handle such problems with a small lookup table, that contains an entry for each conversation with additional columns containing user IDs, ID of last message and timestamp of last message. This would cause an extra UPDATE/INSERT when inserting new message but would massively push performance on viewing INBOX or doing sorts.

Comment: I believe the updated answer I provided below solves your issue in the simplest way possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10747052/302939

Answer (score 6):

hmm maybe i'm not understanding correctly your problem... but to me the solution is quite simple:

```
SELECT c.*, MAX(m.time) as latest_post 
FROM conversations as c 
INNER JOIN messages as m ON c.id = m.conversation_id
WHERE c.userId = 222 OR c.friendId = 222 
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY latest_post DESC
```

here's my test data:

**Conversations :**

```
id  userId  friendId
1   222     333
2   222     444
```

**Messages :**

```
id  message     time (Desc)     conversation_id
14  rty     2012-05-14 19:59:55     2
13  cvb     2012-05-14 19:59:51     1
12  dfg     2012-05-14 19:59:46     2
11  ert     2012-05-14 19:59:42     1
1   foo     2012-05-14 19:22:57     2
2   bar     2012-05-14 19:22:57     2
3   foo     2012-05-14 19:14:13     1
8   wer     2012-05-13 19:59:37     2
9   sdf     2012-05-13 19:59:24     1
10  xcv     2012-05-11 19:59:32     2
4   bar     2012-05-10 19:58:06     1
6   zxc     2012-05-08 19:59:17     2
5   asd     2012-05-08 19:58:56     1
7   qwe     2012-05-04 19:59:20     1
```

**Query result :**

```
id  userId  friendId    latest_post
2   222     444     2012-05-14 19:59:55
1   222     333     2012-05-14 19:59:51
```

If that's not it... just ignore my answer :P

Hope this helps

Comment: It won't work like that because you can't order the grouped results, ideally this would be the perfect scenario.

Comment: @Silver89 you can't specify the order inside a group, but in this case you can sort the data after grouping. The only step you need to do now is to join result with the `usermessages` table to get the messages themselves (group by `usermessage.id` and then join on the same column).

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking for a way to be able to keep all of your current functionality and work flows, yet keep the data in a single table I think you're pretty close.

Instead of having the `conversationId` be a key to a different table, I would instead have it point to the ID of the message that began the conversation.  This would create a parent-child relationship between messages that began a conversation and all those that followed after it.  To be able to see all conversations, you would just select all messages where the `conversationId` is null.  Below is a representation of a 2 message conversation:

```
+----+---------+------+------------------+----------------+--------+----------+
| id | message | read | time             | conversationId | toUser | fromUser |
+----+---------+------+------------------+----------------+--------+----------+
| 1  |  test 1 |  0   | (some timestamp) |  null          |  3     |   4      |
| 2  |  test 2 |  0   | (some timestamp) |   1            |  4     |   3      |
+----+---------+------+------------------+----------------+--------+----------+
```

The conversation was initiated by user 3.  All messages in the conversation can be filter by `conversationId`.  One limitation of this design is that only 2 users can be apart of the conversation.

**Update**

You could get the last message given a conversation id this way:

```
SELECT id, message 
FROM userMessages 
WHERE conversationId = {conversationId} 
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Ah yes that seems like a reasonable solution!

Comment: So if the last user replied to message "test 2" would that have a conversationID of 2 or 1?

Comment: Would you be able to get the last message in a conversation using this approach though? Say if you wanted to list all messages in the inbox with the latest 50 characters of the last message in the conversation, could this be done?

Comment: @Tim My thought was that the hierarchy only goes 2 levels deep (conversation starting message and then all subsequent messages) so the answer to your question would be 1.  This doesn't preclude someone choosing to have a different strategy, though (meaning you could have a deeper tree if you would like)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, if you select all messages where the parentId is null then you will only see the first messages that was sent as the preview, not the latest message

Comment: I found a soloution, if you add another column to the `usermessages` table called `latestPost', you can set this default as 1 and then the latest inserted message in a conversation will be 1, straight after insert you can update the conversation to set all other `lastestPost` to 0. This then allows you to show the list of inbox messages `WHERE latestPost = 1` without any joins or inner selects.

Comment: This isn't very good from the data consistency point of view. You could mix the messages from "unrelated" users, and DBMS would do nothing to stop you (the similar criticism exists for @Silver89's original design, BTW).

Comment: @Branko sure, but if you use any other system incorrectly the same argument applies.

Comment: @watcher My argument is not that the client application could insert incorrect data. My argument is that it could insert _contradicting_ data. The reason this is possible here is that data model is not fully normalized. That doesn't mean normalization is impossible in general case.

Comment: @Branko I understand now.  Its been awhile now since I submitted this answer, and my original understanding was that OP wants to implement this message system using just a single table.  AFAIK there's no way to normalize a many-to-many relationship between users and messages inside a single table

Answer (score 3):

If you can only have one conversation between users, I don't see a reason for a dedicated conversations table. For this query to work fast, you would need a composite index on `(user, message_id)` which is impossible if these fields are in different tables. Move `user_id` and `friend_id` to the `userconversations`. This will make your table `8` bytes per record heavier (even assuming `8`-byte identifiers) which is hardly a problem for a table containing text messages.

If you have few conversations per user with many messages in each, use this:

```
SELECT  um.*
FROM    (
        (
        SELECT  MAX(id) AS messageId
        FROM    usermessages m1
        WHERE   user_id = :me
        GROUP BY
                friend_id
        ORDER BY
                messageId DESC
        LIMIT 10
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
        SELECT  MAX(id) AS messageId
        FROM    usermessages m1
        WHERE   frient_id = :me
        GROUP BY
                user_id
        ORDER BY
                messageId DESC
        LIMIT 10
        )
        ) q
JOIN    usermessages um
ON      um.id = q.messageId
ORDER BY
        id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Create separate indexes on `user_id` and `friend_id`

If you have many conversations with few messages in each, use this query:

```
(
SELECT  *
FROM    usermessages um
WHERE   user_id = :me
        AND id = 
        (
        SELECT  MAX(id)
        FROM    usermessages umi
        WHERE   umi.user_id = um.user_id
                AND umi.friend_id = um.friend_id
        )
ORDER BY
        id DESC
LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT  *
FROM    usermessages um
WHERE   frient_id = :me
        AND id = 
        (
        SELECT  MAX(id)
        FROM    usermessages umi
        WHERE   umi.user_id = um.user_id
                AND umi.friend_id = um.friend_id
        )
ORDER BY
        id DESC
LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY
        id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The idea behind this query is that it just descends all messages for the given user, checking that each message is the last in its conversation. This may be much faster than sorting all last messages for all conversations (if you have many of them).

For this to work fast, create indexes on

```
friend_id
user_id, friend_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Since a given pair of users can have at most one conversation, there is no need to "invent" separate key just to identify conversations. Also, the wording of your question seems to suggest that a message is always sent to a single user, so I'd probably go with something like this:

[image]

Now, there are several things to note about this model:

- It assumes messages between same two users cannot be generated more frequently than the resolution provided by the type used for SEND_TIME.<sup>1</sup>
- The direction of the message is not determined by order of USER1_ID and USER2_ID, but with a separate flag (DIRECTION). This way, a message between given users will always have the same combination of USER1_ID and USER2_ID (enforced by the CHECK above), regardless of who sent and who received the message. This greatly simplifies querying.
- It is unfortunate that [all InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), so the secondary index `I1` is relatively [expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427847/primary-indexes-vs-secondary-indexes-performance-differences/10720128#10720128). There are ways to work around that, but the resulting complications are probably not worth it.

With this data model, it becomes rather easy to sort the "conversations" (identified by user pairs) by the latest message. For example (replace `1` with desired user's USER_ID):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT USER1_ID, USER2_ID, MAX(SEND_TIME) NEWEST
    FROM MESSAGE
    WHERE (USER1_ID = 1 OR USER2_ID = 1)
    GROUP BY USER1_ID, USER2_ID
) Q
ORDER BY NEWEST DESC;
```

*(`OR USER2_ID = 1` is the reason for the secondary index `I1`.)*

If you want not just latest times, but also latest messages, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGE T1
WHERE
    (USER1_ID = 1 OR USER2_ID = 1)
    AND SEND_TIME = (
        SELECT MAX(SEND_TIME)
        FROM MESSAGE T2
        WHERE
            T1.USER1_ID = T2.USER1_ID
            AND T1.USER2_ID = T2.USER2_ID
    )
ORDER BY SEND_TIME DESC;
```

You can play with it in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d689/6).

---

<sup>1</sup> If that's not the case, you can use monotonically-incrementing INT instead, but you'll have to `SELECT MAX(...)` yourself since auto-increment doesn't work on PK subset; or simply make it PK *alone* and have secondary indexes on both USER1_ID and USER2_ID (fortunately, they would be slimmer since the PK is slimmer).

Answer (score 1):

How to create a fast Facebook-like messages system.
tested and widely used by Arutz Sheva users - http://www.inn.co.il (Hebrew).

1. create a "topic" (conversation) table:

   ```
     CREATE TABLE pb_topics (
     t_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     t_last int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     t_user int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (t_id),
     KEY last (t_last)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=137106342 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
   ```
2. create link between user and conversation:

   ```
       CREATE TABLE pb_links (
     l_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     l_user int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     l_new int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     l_topic int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     l_visible int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
     l_bcc int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (l_id) USING BTREE,
     UNIQUE KEY topic-user (l_topic,l_user),
     KEY user-topicnew (l_user,l_new,l_topic) USING BTREE,
     KEY user-topic (l_user,l_visible,l_topic) USING BTREE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64750078 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
   ```
3. create a message

   ```
       CREATE TABLE pb_messages (
     m_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     m_from int(11) NOT NULL,
     m_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1987-11-13 00:00:00',
     m_title varchar(75) NOT NULL,
     m_content mediumtext NOT NULL,
     m_topic int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (m_id),
     KEY date_topic (m_date,m_topic),
     KEY topic_date_from (m_topic,m_date,m_from)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB
   ```

A conversation can be with 2 or more friends (BCC was added like email, but you can skip it).

Insert a new message:
 1. Create new topic
 2. Create Links  for users (from/to)
 3. Add Message
(4. Update users cache table - user have messages)

Add Message to topic:
 Add Message

Select folder:

```
select 
     z.*, group_concat(u_name) as users_name from
         (select max(m_id) as m_id, m_topic as t_id,  m_From, m_title,m_date, l_new 
              from pb_links as l1, pb_messages 
              where l1.l_user=<user>  and m_from < If(inbox, "<>", "=") > and m_topic=l_topic and l1.l_visible=1 
               group by m_topic order by m_id desc limit " & iPage * 35 & ",35) z
           left join  pb_links l2  on (l2.l_topic=t_id)
           left join  users  on (l_user=u_id and l_bcc=0 and l_user<user>)  
            group by l_topic order by m_date desc;
```

In details:

The first is the inner select - this is the fastest way (I was check about 7 other options, checked also in Percona/MariaDB versions) to  get  all messages, and get also the last message to display in the list.
Also look in the inner IF - in inbox, the last message is anyone but not me, and  In outbox - the opposite. LIMIT used for paging.

The outer one used to  add user list (just name comma name string) and more information for **only one message** per topic, and **after paging** (I need to add user list just to the 35-per-page messages, and not for all my large history).

Also, I wrote in hebrew here:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/moshel/archive/2010/08/12/quot-x-quot.aspx
 to create a simple cache table, and forbid the workload of select count from busy message table.

Comment: This seems a little complex considering we have no bcc or topic features. It's more like twitters direct messaging service.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you breaking up the data into conversations?

If it were me, I would use one table called 'usermessages' with the following format:

```
+----+--------+----------+-------------+------------+--------+
| id | userto | userfrom | timecreated | timeviewed | message|
+----+--------+----------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

A conversation is identified by the combination of the 'userto' and 'userfrom' columns. So, when you want to select all of a conversation:

```
SELECT * FROM usermessages 
WHERE (userto = :userto OR userto = :userfrom) 
AND (userfrom = :userfrom OR userfrom = :userto) 
ORDER BY timecreated DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Will work, until you have a 150K messages and the DB became busy and slowly. I tested  ! :-)

Comment: So what's the best way to approach it if your expecting that many messages?

Comment: Look in my answer - very long but tested and works with large and heavy system.

Answer (score 1):

it is being used on fiverr.com and [www.infinitbin.com](http://www.infinitbin.com). I developed the infinitbin own. It has two databases like yours too. the inbox table:-

```
+----+--------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------------------------+
| id | useridto | useridfrom | conversation | last_content | lastviewed | datecreated|
+----+--------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------------------------+
```

This table is very important, used to list the conversations/inbox. The last_content field is 140 charaters from the last message between the conversations. lastviewed is an integer field, the user who lasts sends a message is the last viewed, if the other user in the conversation reads the message. it gets updated to NULL. Therefore to get notifications, you for lastviewed that is not null and not the logged in user's id.

The conversation field is 'userid-userid', therefor strings. To check if users have started a conversation, you concatenate there user_ids with a hyphen and check it.

This kind of messaging system is a very complicating one.

The second table is quite simple.

```
+----+--------+----------+-------------+-------+
| id | inboxid | userid | content | datecreated|
+----+--------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this approach as I don't have access to mysqldb right now. But, I think you should be able to get this done by using a ranking function. Since mysql doesn't have an equivalent of row_number function of Oracle I think you can do it like this:

```
Select * from (
Select 
    uc.id, 
    uc.user_id, 
    uc.friend_id 
    um.message
    um.read, 
    um.time,
    @rownum := IF(@prev_val = um.conversation_id, @rownum + 1, 1) AS rank,
    @prev_val := um.conversation_id
From
    userconversation uc,
    usermessages um,
    (select @row_num:=1) rows,
    (select @prev_val:='') partitions
Where 
    uc.id=um.conversation_id        
    and c.userId = 222 OR c.friendId = 222 

Order By 
    um.conversation_id,um.id desc
)t where t.rank=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set it up like this

### Table details

```
conversations (#id, last_message_id)

participation (#uid1, #uid2, conversation_id)

messages (#conversation_id, #id, uid, contents, read, *time)
```

**conversations**

This table will be used mainly to generate a new identifier for each conversation, together with a calculated field of the last update (for optimization). The two users have been disconnected from this table and moved into `participation`.

**participation**

This table records the conversations between two users **in both directions**; to explain why, take a look at the following key:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD PRIMARY(uid1, uid2);
```

While this is good for both enforcing the uniqueness and simple lookups, you should be aware of the following behavior:

- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid1=1 AND uid2=2`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid1=1`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid1=1 AND uid2>5`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid2=2`

The first two queries perform very well, MySQL also optimizes identity lookups on the first part of your key. The third one also yields pretty good performance as the second part of your key can be used for range queries. The last query doesn't perform well at all because the index is "left biased" and therefore it performs a full table scan.

**messages**

This table stores the actual sent messages, comprising the conversation identifier, sender id, contents, read flag and the time it was sent.

### Operation

**sending messages**

To determine whether a conversation between two users has already been established you can simply query the `participation` table:

```
SELECT conversation_id FROM participation WHERE uid1=:sender_id AND uid2=:receiver_id
```

If it does not yet exist, you create both records:

```
INSERT INTO conversations (last_message_id) VALUES (NULL);
# fetch last insert id here
INSERT INTO participation VALUES (:sender_id, :receiver_id, :conversation_id), (:receiver_id, :sender_id, :conversation_id);
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (:conversation_id, 0, :sender_id, :message_contents, 0, NOW());
UPDATE conversations SET last_message_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = :conversation_id
```

If the conversation is already setup:
    INSERT INTO messages VALUES (:conversation_id, 0, :sender_id, :message_contents, 0, NOW());
    UPDATE conversations SET last_message_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = :conversation_id

Note: the UPDATE statement can be scheduled as LOW_PRIORITY because you don't always have to be 100% correct.

**conversation overview**

This has become a simpler query:

```
SELECT other_user.name, m.contents, m.read, c.id
FROM participation AS p
INNER JOIN user AS other_user ON other_user.id = p.uid2
INNER JOIN conversation AS c ON c.id = p.conversation_id
INNER JOIN messages AS m ON m.id = c.last_message_id
WHERE p.uid1 = :user_id
ORDER BY m.time DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this, but the write-up should make sense to you.

### Optimization

Another reason why it's good to have a two-way table is so that it's prepared for sharding, a method in which you push related data into another database (on a different machine); based on certain rules you would determine where to fetch the information from.

You could move the data in these ways:

1. divide the `participation` table up based on the `uid1` field
2. divide the `messages` table up based on the `conversation_id` field

The messages overview will get more complicated as you're likely being forced to make two queries; this can be mitigated somewhat with caches (and in extreme case document databases) though.

Hope this gives you some ideas on future planning :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to create a userconversation table.

If only user can have only one conversation with someone, the unique id for this thread is a concat between userId and friendId. So I move the friendId column in usersmessage table. The problem of order (friendId-userId is the same thread of userId-friendId) can be solved so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(GREATEST(userId,FriendId),"_",LEAST(userId,FriendId)) AS threadId
```

Now there is a problem of fetch the last message after a GROUP BY threadId.

I think is a good solution make a concat between DATE and message and after a MAX on this field.

I assume, for simplicity, column date is a DATETIME field ('YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s') but it not need because there is FROM_UNIXTIME function.

So the final query is

```
SELECT 
        CONCAT(GREATEST(userId,FriendId),"_",LEAST(userId,FriendId)) AS threadId,
        friendId, MAX(date) AS last_date, 
        MAX(CONCAT(date,"|",message)) AS last_date_and_message 

FROM usermessages
WHERE userId = :userId OR friendId = :userId
GROUP BY threadId ORDER BY last_date DESC
```

the result of field last_date_and_message is something like so:

```
2012-05-18 00:18:54|Hi my friend this is my last message
```

it can be simply parsed from your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

The simpleste way I think for this is:

**Tables:**

```
conversation(cid | userId | friendId | last_message_id)
messages(mid | message | userId | read | time | cid)
```

Then update last_message_id after each message insert by users in particulate conversation.

And then run this simple query. It will give you what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM conversation c, messages m 
WHERE (c.userId='$uid' OR c.friendId='$uid')
AND c.last_msg_id=m.message_id
ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

$uid is id of logged in user.

So in actual what this process is doing:

1. Displaying all conversation of logged in user.
2. Referencing last message (so you do not need group by)
3. And last displaying messages in order by desc.

Answer (score -1):

Extending the answer suggested by Watcher.

You should consider dropping the "conversation" concept to simplify further.

```
+----+---------+------+------------------+--------+----------+
| id | message | read | time             | toUser | fromUser |
+----+---------+------+------------------+--------+----------+
| 1  |  test 1 |  0   | (some timestamp) |  3     |   4      |
| 2  |  test 2 |  0   | (some timestamp) |  4     |   3      |
+----+---------+------+------------------+--------+----------+
```

List of all conversations for user 123:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, message, toUser, fromUser   
    FROM userMessages 
    WHERE toUser = 123 OR fromUser = 123 
    ORDER BY id DESC
) AS internalTable 
GROUP BY toUser, fromUser
```

List entire conversation between user 123 and user 456:

```
SELECT * 
FROM userMessages
WHERE (toUser = 123 OR fromUser = 123) 
AND (toUser = 456 OR fromUser = 456)
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: The group by doesn't work because the order runs on the grouped item (the oldest id) and thus returns the wrong rows. Otherwise this would be the perfect way to do it.

Comment: Slight adjustment to the query. How bout that?