# What is Secondary indexes in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I had a confusion while reading an article about the Mysql storage engine what are Secondary indexes?

Could any explain this briefly?

Comment: Have a look here at [What is difference between primary index and secondary index exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824686/what-is-difference-between-primary-index-and-secondary-index-exactly) may be it can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between primary index and secondary index exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824686/what-is-difference-between-primary-index-and-secondary-index-exactly)